# How to get this php $_GET value?

Tags: php, get

I have a link of this format `http://localhost:8012/image.php?2`

That returns a result of `print_r($_GET)` like this

```
Array ( [2] => ) string(0) ""
```

For exmaple `http://localhost:8012/image.php?3`
Would return

```
Array ( [3] => ) string(0) ""
```

I have no idea how to get that 2/3 value, tried everything

Comment: It’s not a value, it’s a key.

Comment: Knowing it's a key does not help to know which it is. 2 or 3, depending on the URL.

Comment: To get the key of the first query param, you could do: `$val = array_keys($_GET)[0] ?? null;` or `$val = key($_GET);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_GET` is an associative array. See https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.get.php#98419 about how GET HTTP variables are handled.

You should use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parse it.

In your case, with url `http://localhost:8012/image.php?2`:

- `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` = `2`
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` = `/image.php?2`

Try different URLs with these two variables to see what they contain.

Once you have your value, you have to parse it. In the case with `QUERY_STRING`:

```
$image_id = preg_replace('`^([0-9]+)`', '$1', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

It's important to check the URL, because you never know what a user can pass in the URL.

In the case with `REQUEST_URI`:

```
$image_id = preg_replace('`^image\.php\?([0-9]+)`', '$1', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

FYI: what you are trying to do is the role of a router. Have a look at https://route.thephpleague.com/ to understand how a library can help you make it MUCH easier and MUCH more secure.